# Scala Play app always times out on first request

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

After starting my app for the first time, the first request always times out. If I tail the logs when this request is invoked, Play appears to be doing some kind of required post compilation work- resolving the same list of dependencies that were resolved on startup and initiating the database connection. Is there any way to force this extra work on startup?

Comment: How do you run it?

Answer (score 0):

When you run in prod mode this will not happen.
Even if your not building yet for production you can 
[run a test instance](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying#Running-a-test-instance)

You will need to be sure to set an [application secret](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ApplicationSecret#The-Application-Secret)

Comment: What your describing is the experience you get when running play in dev mode.